# Trying to perform a goal seek with vba with goal as changeable value

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am facing a problem with a button I have. I wanna create a button that performs a goal seek analysis when clicking it.
The goal seek function is a simple reversed DCF calculation where it should find the implied growth rate for a current stock price.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Price As String, ImpliedPrice As String
Set ws = Sheet2
Set ws1 = Sheet6

ws.Select
Price = Range("C11")

ws1.Select
ws1.Range("G39").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Price


ws1.Select
Range("G38").GoalSeek Goal:=Price, ChangingCell:=("G8")

End Sub
```

The variables are the following:
Sheet2 is the place where I get the current price from and Sheet6 is where the DCF model is and the goal seek should be performed.

G38 = A reference to the Implied share price, in the referenced cell I simple divide Equity value by outstanding shares to also be able to use the DCF in the normal way.

G8 = the revenue growth rate assumption

When performing the code the 1004 run time error appears but I am not exactly sure why?
It would be great if someone could help me figure out why there is this runtime error.
Thanks already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set worksheet variables for what u re selecting sheets?

try below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Price As String, ImpliedPrice As String
Set ws = thisworkbook.worksheets(Sheet2.name)
Set ws1 = thisworkbook.worksheets(Sheet6.name)

Price = ws .Range("C11")

ws1.Range("G39") = Price

ws1.Range("G38").GoalSeek Goal:=Price, ChangingCell:=ws1.range("G8")

End Sub
```

Comment: ah that works perfectly, thanks a lot. Yeah, I am relatively new to VBA so didn't know you could do it directly. Anyways thanks again that was helpful